# a (bigger than 1) is always bigger than its roots

Tags: analysis, roots

how can I formally proof that for a > 1: $$ a> \sqrt a > \sqrt[3]a > \sqrt[4]a ...  $$?
Can someone help? ;)

Comment: You can show that $a^{1/x}$ is decreasing.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Can you show that a^(n+1) > a^n ?

Comment: We haven't defined this expression yet :/

Answer (score 2):

To show $\sqrt[n]a>\sqrt[n+1]a$, raise both sides to $n(n+1)$ to obtain
$$
a^{n+1}>a^n
$$
and prove the latter inequality from $a>1$.

Comment: Can I prove this by induction over n ?

Comment: Yes. Only find the suitable factor to get from $a^n>a^{n-1}$ to $a^{n+1}>a^{n}$

Comment: For the induction step I have: y^(n+1) = y*y^n < y*y^(n+1) = y^(n+2)

Comment: is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use logarithms to show that
$$a^{\frac{1}{n}}>a^{\frac{1}{n+1}}$$

Answer (score -1):

Set $a:=e^b,$ where $b>0;$

Then

$e^b>e^{b/2}>.....e^{b/n}>e^{b/(n+1)}$ since $f(x)=e^x$ is an increasing function.